# State- and serverless connection beween .NET applications

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, broadcast, serverless

I have a ASP.NET web application which can be installed on multiple machines in the same LAN for load-balancing and failover purposes. In addition, there is a Windows service which can be installed on multiple machines in the network which performs regluarly occuring background tasks.

I don't have a dedicated server machine and I don't know how many instances of the web application or Windows service are running. Example setup:

Machine 1:

- 1x ASP.NET Web Application
- 1x Windows Service

Machine 2:

- 1x ASP.NET Web Application

Machine 3:

- 1x Windows Service

Now I'm looking for a way to establish a state- and more important serverless connection between those applications.
Generally it would be sufficient if any of the nodes could send a broadcast message (with payload) which is automatically received by all other nodes on the same machine and other machines. I don't need two-way communication here, one way messages would do the job.

Comment: If you able to use some cloud services i think you can take a look into some exiting cloud service bus solutions. Or you can try to make simple own broker application and host it in separated server

Comment: So you need multicast, and so you need UDP. The question is, are you tolerant about possible data loss?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use cloud services for that (might be an environment without internet connection) and I can't accept loss of data, too.